# Error when debugging Xamarin Project on Android Exception: "Default constructor not found for type "[MyApp].Views.AboutPage"

Tags: c#, android, debugging, xamarin, xamarin.android

Im getting an error when trying to Debug/Deploy my App (that works on UWP) to Android.
I have tried to run the App on the emulator in VS (Android 9) and my smartphone (Android12).

The error i am getting is "Default constructor not found on type [MyApp].Views.AboutPage".

The AboutPage class:

```
public partial class AboutPage : ContentPage
      {
         public AboutPage()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
             BindingContext = new AboutViewModel();
         }
     }
```

As in this class, I do not have any non default constructors in my entire Application.

I have already tried to set the linker setting to "Sdk Assemblies only", which resulted in a different error.
When trying to debug a Microsoft-Default project on my smartphone it worked with the same settings as in my app. The contents of the AboutPage class do not differ between these two projects.

Comment: Show the xaml code too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception was caused by a DependencyService, removed it and it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem. You can first try to delete the bin folders and the obj folders and rebuild it.  If it doesn’t work, try to restart the visual studio.

If the problem persists, you can try to recheck if there are some problems in your code.

Comment: I just tried this: 
1. `Get-ChildItem .\ -include bin,obj -Recurse | foreach ($_) { remove-item $_.fullname -Force -Recurse }` -in Powershell, to Delete all bin and obj files
2. Rebuild the Solution
3. Restart VS, yet the error is still happening

Comment: Could you please a basic demo so that we can try to test on our side?